# C code of simple Receiver

Tags: c, char

I have this code of a transmitter and I have a problem where when I get input from my transmitter I save it in a char array "rec" and after I have finished receiving I compare it with my other arrays and base on that comparison I light up a bulb in portb. But the code gives me no errors and no bulb lights (the connection works I've tried it) it has something to do with the comparing arrays part. Am I doing this right? Thank you

```
char rec[3];
char cmp1[]= "1000";
char cmp2[]= "1010";
char cmp3[]="1111";
char cmp4[]="1001";
int i=0;
int beginrecord;
void main(void)
{
TRISB=0;
TRISD=0;
TRISC=255;
PORTC=0;
PORTB=0;

       while(1)
       {
             if(PORTC==1)
             {
             rec[i]=1;
             i++;
             beginrecord = 1;
              delay_ms(1);
             }

             if (PORTC==0 && beginrecord==1)
            {
                rec[i]=0;
                i++;
                delay_ms(1);

            }

            if(i==4) {
            beginrecord = 0;
            i = 0;
            if(rec == cmp1){
            portb = 0x01;}
            else if(rec == cmp2){
            portb = 0x02;}
            else if(rec == cmp3){
            portb = 0x04;}
            else if(rec == cmp4){
            portb = 0x08;}

            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code has a number of issues.  . `beginrecord` not initialized before potential first is `if (PORTC==0 && beginrecord==1)`.  2. `char cmp1[]= "1000";`, etc., should not be a string.  Recommend a char array `char cmp1[4]= {1,0,0,0}` 3. char rec[3]; s/b char rec[4];  4.  The 2 `if(PORTC ..)` seem to only detect patterns 1,0,0,0.  5. Recommend standard indentation.  6. Compare s/b `memcmp(rec, cmp1, 4)`.

Answer (score 2):

You must use `strcmp(rec, cmp1) == 0`  instead of `rec == cmp1`.

The way you do it now, you compare only the pointers, which are never the same.

And are you sure that your port returns a character `1`or `0` and not the values 0/1?

In that case your comparison also wouldn't work.

Some other issues with your code:

1. I assume that the char form the port is a binary value and not an ASCII character.
2. If it is indeed an ASCII character and you use strcmp() then you must add a zero byte at the end of the buffer.
3. If you receive multiple bytes and not bits, you must use memcmp() instead of strcmp(). In that case your intialisation of cmpX would be also wrong. If it are bits you receive, you would want to combine them into bytes before comparing (assuming a serial port).
4. PORTC is always 0, so it can not become 1 in your code.
5. You seem to have mixed case PORTB vs. portb.
6. your variables have no type.

Comment: Yes, I thought so. I assume that the code has many problems, but without knowing the protocoll it's hard to say.

Comment: thanks it returns ints but I dont copy them to my array, I made my arrays unsigned ints and that did it

Comment: "PORTC is always 0" is not true in this case.  PORTC is an I/O interface whose input values are of the external world (TRISC=255).  An implied declaration, but not shown, for PORTC (PORTB, etc.) would imply something like `volatile char PORTC;` OP should have tagged this a "PIC".

Comment: @chux, yeah, that would have been helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are declare three `cmp[]` of char type which is a string so it is like "1000". it is 4 byte data. and your `rec[3]` is only 3 byte. i think you try to compare a int type. like

```
1001 == 1001 in binary
```

Declare them as `unsigned int` then try to compare.

And make all your values full 8 bit like `00001000b` not `1000`. 
or may be i get it wrong.

Comment: very well, you should read some tutorial on "how to code in c for controller" for best practice and better code.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues that confuse your goal - see above comment, but I've tried to address them below.

Rather than accumulate the `rec` as an array, the bits are accumulated in an `int`.  This simplifies the compares to your original style.

`beginrecord` needed initialization.  Variables were brought into a local scope.

Cleaned up the indentation.

```
const int cmp1 = 8;  // "1000";
const int cmp2 = 10; // "1010";
const int cmp3 = 15; // "1111";
const int cmp4 = 9;  // "1001";
void main(void) {
  TRISB = 0;
  TRISD = 0;
  TRISC = 255;
  PORTC = 0;
  PORTB = 0;

  int i = 0;
  int beginrecord = 0;
  int rec = 0;
  while (1) {
    if (PORTC == 1) {
      rec <<= 1; /* rec = rec * 2 */
      rec |= 1;
      beginrecord = 1;
      delay_ms(1);
      i++;
    }
    else if (PORTC == 0 && beginrecord == 1) {
      rec <<= 1;
      delay_ms(1);
      i++;
    }
    if (i == 4) {
      if (rec == cmp1) {
        PORTB = 0x01;
      } else if (rec == cmp2) {
        PORTB = 0x02;
      } else if (rec == cmp3) {
        PORTB = 0x04;
      } else if (rec == cmp4) {
        PORTB = 0x08;
      }
      beginrecord = 0;
      i = 0;
      rec = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes I should have thought of that! Thank you soo much! I dont know why It didnt even cross my mind :D